# Moving Specific Number of files using Batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

Need some help with a batch script that will allow me to move a specific number of files in a loop to a created new folder structure following an excel file which specifics the new folder number append (. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7...) and in the second column has the corresponding number of frames to be moved (121,100,44,33...).

The syntax of the file names are the same, just with the number of cell padding recursively increasing
Eg:
another000001.dpx, another000002.dpx, another000003.dpx etc

The first generated folder should have a name like Shot1 and 121 files should be moved to the new folder reading from the excel
The second folder should be named Shot2 and 100 files should be moved to the new folder from the top reading from the excel
And so on...

Someone help?

Comment: Reading cells out of an excel spreadsheet are beyond the capabilities of a batch script. Now if you had a set, incrementable integer where you can start at 1 and need to go to 987128746957173 it's possible =D

Answer (score 0):

Well, thats too much to ask of anyone to write that for you but you could start with this:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir /b') DO (
   CALL SET /a x = !x! +1
   if !x! == 1 (
      CALL ECHO ---------- printing %%a
      CALL TYPE %%a .. 
   )
)
pause
```